# mediaelement.js does not start before download complete

Tags: mediaelement.js

MediaElement.js works fine, except for one little thing. The flash version does not start playing until the video has been completely downloaded. This is shown by its own progressbar that always "buffers" to 100% before starting to play. Before then, repeatedly hitting the play/pause button does nothing.

The HTML5 version starts playing right away, indicating it is not a server setting.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

possible, it is on your video file encoding...
try this tool:
QTIndexSwapper2

Comment: What exactly are you saying might be wrong? Please remember the video plays fine in everything.